# maven build with my local-module artifactory (library)

Tags: java, maven, heroku, intellij-idea

I created a project named `app-service` that uses a core module(`app-core`). I include this core module in my project as maven dependency through `<systemPath>` that reside in project base directory.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>app-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/app-core-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

I configure maven and run goal

```
mvn clean package install

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 44.733 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-04-05T12:27:46+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 29M/533M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

After `BUILD SUCCESS` `$CLASSPATH` does not contain the app-core.jar file, expect this it include all dependencies that listed in maven `<dependencies>`

I want to use this app-core module as `compile` scope. When I try this it prompt error

```
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for app-group:app-core:jar must be omitted. This field may only be specified for a dependency with system scope. @ line 71, column 25
```

**Note: I do not upload this `app-core` on public repository due to security purpose. I want to use through project base directory because I need to deploy the same on `Heroku`.**

---

**Update**

I googled it and found a plugin that installs local repository.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-external</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${project.basedir}/app-core-0.1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar</file>
                <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                <groupId>app-group</groupId>
                <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

But the result is same......

Answer (score 1):

You should follow this guide to [Adding Unmanaged Dependencies to a Maven Project](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/local-maven-dependencies) on Heroku. To summarize the guide, run:

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///path/to/app-group/app-core/ -Dfile=app-core-1.0.jar -DgroupId=app-group -DartifactId=app-core -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=1.0
```

Then add this repository to your `pom.xml`:

```
<repository>
  <id>project.local</id>
  <name>project</name>
  <url>file:${project.basedir}/repo</url>
</repository>
```

Then use the dependency i your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>app-group</groupId>
  <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried same but maven builds failure with error `Could not resolve dependencies for project app-group:app-services: jar:0.11-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find app-group:app-core:jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT in <my_repository_url>.`

my repositories contain two repository one is my internal-central-repository and another one repository with url `<url>file:${project.basedir}/</url>`

Comment: I used a plugin for installing my app-core `maven-install-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is telling you to delete part how you setup your dependency.
Try omitting parts of it such as:

```
<systemPath>${project.basedir}</systemPath>
```

..and working from there.

Edit:

I would also try the most limited amount of information.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>app-group</groupId>
    <artifactId>app-core</artifactId>
    <version>${project.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Try changing the project version even.  I've had problems with maven dependencies not pulling from repositories because the pom.xml was written incorrectly. The way I ended up solving them was to keep trying different ways of writing the dependency until it actually pulled it correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried same but maven builds failure with error `Could not resolve dependencies for project app-group:app-services: jar:0.11-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find app-group:app-core:jar:0.1.1-SNAPSHOT in <my_repository_url>`. it not search in my local project folder where my app-code reside.